# how to print a 8 bit value in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am sorry to bother my mentors.Last few days I posted few queries.And they have extended their hand to help me. 
By working through NASM in Ubuntu11.04 at x86 machine, recently I found another confusion in working. It is "How can i print 8 bit value"?
Suppose the snippet of code of mine look like:

```
    section .data
         var db "string"
    section .text
         global main
    main:
         nop
         xor ebx,ebx

         mov dl,byte[var+ebx]
         mov al, dl  ; setting to AL the ASCII character to write
         mov bh, 0   ; setting the page number to 0 (all in the same page)
         mov bl, 7   ; setting to bl the foreground pixel color
         mov ah, 0xE ; INT10 E sub mode --> Write Text in Teletype Mode
         int 10      ; "calling" to the interrupt.

         nop
```

Now, I want to print only the dl. The above code used the tips of @Shmil The Cat. and it raises segmentation fault. How can we resolve this?

THank you in Advance.

Comment: Can you use C runtime functions ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat: No. I knoe tht i cant use here PUSH DL cmmand also. for this reason, I am asking help

Comment: @AntoineMathys: Hello Sir! I am working in neither dos or windows. I'm working on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux you can use putchar:

```
        global main
        extern putchar

        section .data
        var db "string"

        section .text
main:
         mov ebx, 0  ; index
         mov dl, [var + ebx]
         push edx
         call putchar
         add esp, 4
         ret
```

To call a function that expects a char you push a whole word. The function will use the least significant byte.

Comment: I think part of the problem isn't using C runtime functions ... see the comments above

Comment: @Antoine Mathys: Thank you very much, mentor. It solves my problem.I am really grateful to you